# Switch between activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to switch between my Main Actvity and my second Activity, but whenever I do it the app shuts down.
So after i click the button1 "Neues Feld", the App should switch to the second activity: feldlayout.class with the layout: feldlayout.xml! The activities are liested in the Android_MAnifest, that's also not the problem...

Thank you for the help! **It's working now!** I made a new View class, added it to the layout and then it worked fine!

**Main Class**

```
package com.example.volleyballapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main_Layout extends Activity {

 Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
     b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     b1.setOnClickListener(myhandler);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main__layout, menu);
    return true;
}

View.OnClickListener myhandler = new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v==b1){
    Intent i = new Intent(Main_Layout.this, feldlayout.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }   
}
};}
```

**Main Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background2"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"   
tools:context=".Main_Layout" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
    android:text=" "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/farbe" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:background="@drawable/bnt_black"
    android:onClick="NeuesFeldClick"
    android:text="Neues Feld" />

  <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="100dp"

          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:text=" "
          android:id="@+id/textView2"

          android:textColor="@color/farbe"
          android:layout_below="@id/button1"/>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button2"
     style="@style/ButtonText"
     android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:background="@drawable/bnt_black"
     android:onClick="LetztesFeldClick"
     android:text="Letztes Feld" />

  <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="100dp"

          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:text=" "
          android:id="@+id/textView3"

          android:textColor="@color/farbe"
          android:layout_below="@id/button2"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bnt_black"
    android:onClick="SavesClick"
    android:text="Gespeicherte Felder" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Second Activity**

```
package com.example.volleyballapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class feldlayout extends Activity{
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.feldlayout);


   }

  private Paint paint = new Paint();
  private Path path = new Path();
  int count = 1;

  public feldlayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);           //Breite des Strichs
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);        //Farbe des Strichs 
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

  }

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if ((count%2 != 0)){
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);}
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        count++;

        if(count%2 != 1){
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
      return true;
        }
        if(count%2 != 0){
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
        }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      // nothing to do
      break;
    default:
      return false;
    }
    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
  }
private void invalidate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}   
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace. It will show the exception

Comment: try to create an empty constructor in your feldlayout class.

Comment: You're conflating an Activity subclass and a View subclass. Don't do that. Separate out the View subclass into its own class.

Comment: @MikeM.  What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Short answer: Cut out everything after `onCreate()` and put it in another class that `extends View`.

Comment: Ok! And how can I connect the View with the feldlayout Activity now?

Comment: Treat it just like a Button, or a TextView, or any other View. (Btw, you have to use my @name or I won't see your comments.)

Comment: @MikeM. i'll try it, it's not so easy for me^^

Comment: @MikeM. Can you give me a code example please? I would be very thankful!

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah half, I have the problem that I added it to the Layout, but I can't draw the lines now, the layout appears but I think it's not in the forderground or something like this... do you understand what i mean?

Comment: You need to remove the `invalidate()` method that was automatically generated. Other than that, though, you'll need to post a new question, as it's a different problem.

Comment: @MikeM. It was already removed and it's not showing the lines ._. , will be a long night ._.'

Comment: @MikeM. I did it, I'm so glad, now the next challenges can come^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just i tried. your code is working. The problem is you call `Constructor` in the second Activity. Below one.

```
 public feldlayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);           //Breite des Strichs
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);        //Farbe des Strichs 
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

  }
```

Please remove this constructor and try again.

**Note**
Just create a separate class and call the `constructor` there.

Comment: thx for the answer, I tried the idea of Mike M. and that seems to work fine!

Comment: Exactly what i mean the same. If you got the answer then i am happy. Thanks